# Incorrect Display of Hangul (Korean) Characters After Update to Fedora 32

Tags: linux, fedora, fonts, kde-plasma-5

I've recently upgraded to Fedora 32 using KDE Plasma 5.18.5, and regardless of the font displayed, in a graphical, user setting, Hangul characters invariably are stacked on upon another, making them illegible. Meanwhile, katakana, hiragana, and kanji all display properly. Uninstalling the package `wqy-microhei-fonts` means that all the characters are properly spaced, however, they are all rendered as missing glyphs.

Sample affected applications include:

- ABIWord
- Firefox
- KWrite
- Spotify
- Chromium

Unaffected Applications Include:

- Konsole
- Gnome Terminal

Interestingly, only the search bar of Chromium does not have the render bug, while the rest of the Chromium application incorrectly displays these characters. Meanwhile, Firefox in its entirety is affected.

Here is a sample image of Chromium (displaying both the proper and improper rendering of fonts). Any suggestions, or help to properly display these fonts would be greatly appreciated:

[image: Showing Both Correct & Incorrect Display]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the suggestion of someone else, even when not using Noto fonts, installing `google-noto-cjk-fonts` is required to fix this. Make sure to restart any affected applications after installing this package for rendering changes to take effect.